# uknown column in field list trigger

Tags: mysql

What is the issue here? I'm using workbench. When i try to insert into my table staff i get an error.

I'm trying to insert into another table values from the ;staff' depending if on an input to the one of the columns.

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'position' in 'field list' 0.046 sec


    CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger_name
    AFTER INSERT ON staff
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   if position = 'senior instructor' 
   then
       INSERT INTO NEW.senior_instructor 
       VALUES (NEW.employee_name, NEW.date_of_birth);

    end if;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delimiter ||

CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger_name
    AFTER INSERT ON staff
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   if NEW.position = 'senior instructor' 
   then
       INSERT INTO senior_instructor 
       VALUES (NEW.employee_name, NEW.date_of_birth);

    end if;
END
||
delimiter ;
```

Comment: That does allow input into the table but the trigger fails still. It does not insert the values into senior_instructor.

Comment: So the trigger does not throw an error but no data is inserted into the other table? Well then your position column does not contsain the value `senior instructor` when you insert data. Also you should name the columns of the `senior_instructor` table you want to insert into

Comment: Thank you, the issue was me not naming the columns!